# Shopify API 250 Product Limit with Pagination and Sorting

Tags: shopify-api

We are integrating Shopify into a content management system.  We ran into a snag where we discovered the 250 products limit in the REST API response and there are a few collections that have more than 250 products.  We've played around with page_info to get at more than 250 products, but been trying to figure out how you would use that along with sort ordering (i.e. Prices low to high, or products ordered A to Z)?  Seems simple enough to use page_info to create pagination of the products on a page by page basis, but how do you also sort the products for the whole collection?  I assume there must be another way to pull a full collection into the website using the REST API, paginate the products using a user designated number of products per page (i.e. 48 products per page) and allow the user to sort all of the products (i.e. prices low to high) in the way they desire.  Strangely I haven't found documentation that shows how to do all three. In particular I don't see how to sort on the whole collection.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried querying the API, but discovered there is a 250 product limit and some collections we have are larger than that.  Then tried page_info, but not seeing a way to sort the products when doing this.  Searched documenation on how to sort when having more than 250 products, but haven't found anything on that yet.